# Proper way to send tokens to frontend app for Firebase custom Oauth login

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth, firebase, steam

I am new to this and I don't know if I am doing this right...

I am using node.js with express to generate auth tokens for a custom Oauth service that Firebase does not support(Steam).

From my frontend a Angular app I redirect the user to the /login get route on my express server and the user is then redirected to the oauth provider page to complete registration.

Upon completion the user gets back to my express server where I compute the firebase token and then send it to the frontend as a cookie and then redirect the user back to the frontend where I complete the sigin process using the token in the cookie.

Am I doing this right? If not can you please quide me in the right direction...thank you.